# Wrong leap second December 2015

Tags: ntp, leap-second

I have found that an extra leap second has been inserted in my system on December 2015.

Looking into the /var/log/messages file, I have found that one leap second has been inserted on June 30th 2015, which is correct and another extra on December 30th 2015, that is an error.

My kernel version and ntp:

Kernel: 3.0.13-0.27-pae
Ntp version: 4.2.4p8

How can I know how many leap seconds are currently inserted in my system?
I am using ntp.

Thank you very much, 
Javi.

Comment: Exactly how do you know (i.e. what are the log messages)?  I have a program that runs continuously to monitor leap seconds and automatically records the transitions.  Based upon the way `ntp` handles this, it's very difficult to spot.  And, it would be Dec 31 [at ~23:59:59].

Comment: Thank you Craig for your answer, That is the kernel messages file, in my linux distribution is under /var/log/messages: the exact message is: "kernel: [3615119.207916] Clock: inserting leap second 23:59:60 UTC and it happens at 23:59:59 December 31st.

Comment: I realize that, but what is the _exact_ text?  No leap second was scheduled for end-of-year [and, again, it's 31st, not 30th].  What was the exact time of the message (down to ns if possible)? If it was inserted for you, it would be inserted worldwide.  ntp resyncs so everybody gets the same clock, so if ntp did mess up, what you want is what every ntp client system has [even if wrong].  The message is bogus (i.e. nothing happened). The "detection" mechanism returned a false positive. Your ntp daemon may just be drifting [delta is too high]. Consider `ntpdate -b` to force correction

Comment: Also, look at `/etc/adjtime`

Comment: See http://www.iers.org/SharedDocs/News/EN/BulletinC.html  I looked at the kernel source that generated your message.  IMO [as a kernel programmer], it has issues.  And, even if the kernel _did_ insert a leap second into the system clock, it will be taken out when the NTP daemon resyncs.  So, it's long gone.  Find a system that has _no_ such message.  Then, do: `date ; ssh remote date ; date` a few times and you'll probably find no difference.  Remember to do `ntpdate -b` as well.  Seriously, no worries ...

Comment: The exact text is: kernel: [3615119.207916] Clock: inserting leap second 23:59:60 UTC" and it happens at 23:59:59 December 31. I know that there was not any leap second programmed at that time, I have two of these messages, the first one occurred on June 30th (as programmed an correct) and the second one occured on December 31st (incorrect), the system is isolated from internet. The current drift time is 10.31

Comment: Thanks again Craig, I do have to worry, the second has indeed entered into the system, I am monitoring some drifttimes between ground and a satellite, and from the 1st of Jan, it is one second, because of the leap second.

Comment: kernel screwed up and _did_ insert [bogus] leap second.  But, now ntpd will _not_ resync because delta is too large (>1sec). Look at /etc/ntp/step-tickers [or /etc/ntp.conf] to get ntp host name. Then [sudo]: `systemctl stop ntpd ; ntpdate -b <hostname> ; systemctl start ntpd`. ntpdate will print an "offset".  If >1sec, this confirms what I've been saying. Now, everything should be synced. FYI, the timestamp in your message is dmesg type: fractional seconds since last boot

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers Craig, the offset is 0.9 and the drift is 2.8 PPM. I have finally managed to check whether the system has or not the correct time by checking the date against my local machine accesing by ssh to the servers, and the time is correct, I can not understand why (two leap seconds have been added in 2015 according to the system logs), but so far is ok. Again thank you very much for your support.

Comment: You're welcome. kernel code uses a [too] "clever" autodetect for this based on "seeing" a difference and adjusts system clock. But diff can occur for _other_ reasons (clock glitch)->false positive. When I created my pgms, I avoided this approach as _unreliable_ [as evidenced by what happened to you]. IMO, the only way to detect is to "know" [based on IERS table lookup]. (e.g.) You can't do time(jan05) and time(aug01) and look at localtime's and "find" the difference because of the way ntp does things. The diff will be the same regardless of a jun30 event or not.

Answer (score 0):

The NTP protocol does not need knowledge of historic leap seconds.  It does need to know ahead of time and it does this with the leap indicator bits in its packets.  If leap seconds are missed or extra ones are inserted, NTP will basically re-sync them away.  The official record of leap seconds is here (along with the official misspelling of "beetween"):

```
"#  Value of TAI-UTC in second valid beetween the initial value until
#  the epoch given on the next line. The last line reads that NO
#  leap second was introduced since the corresponding date 
#  Updated through IERS Bulletin 62 issued in July 2021
#  
#
#  File expires on 28 June 2022
#
#
#    MJD        Date        TAI-UTC (s)
#           day month year
#    ---    --------------   ------   
#
    41317.0    1  1 1972       10
    41499.0    1  7 1972       11
    41683.0    1  1 1973       12
    42048.0    1  1 1974       13
    42413.0    1  1 1975       14
    42778.0    1  1 1976       15
    43144.0    1  1 1977       16
    43509.0    1  1 1978       17
    43874.0    1  1 1979       18
    44239.0    1  1 1980       19
    44786.0    1  7 1981       20
    45151.0    1  7 1982       21
    45516.0    1  7 1983       22
    46247.0    1  7 1985       23
    47161.0    1  1 1988       24
    47892.0    1  1 1990       25
    48257.0    1  1 1991       26
    48804.0    1  7 1992       27
    49169.0    1  7 1993       28
    49534.0    1  7 1994       29
    50083.0    1  1 1996       30
    50630.0    1  7 1997       31
    51179.0    1  1 1999       32
    53736.0    1  1 2006       33
    54832.0    1  1 2009       34
    56109.0    1  7 2012       35
    57204.0    1  7 2015       36
    57754.0    1  1 2017       37"
--https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second
```